# Mapper and Reducer are Generic in Hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop

im studying the Mapper and the Reducer class in Hadoop. The thing i cant understand is why these classes are defined as Generic. What does it involves ?

I always studied generic for lists and array purposes and in this case i dont understand their use. 
Can you help me ?

An example of mapper is

```
 public class TokenCounterMapper 
     extends Mapper<Object, Text, Text, IntWritable>{

   private final static IntWritable one = new IntWritable(1);
   private Text word = new Text();

   public void map(Object key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
     StringTokenizer itr = new StringTokenizer(value.toString());
     while (itr.hasMoreTokens()) {
       word.set(itr.nextToken());
       context.write(word, one);
     }
   }
 }
```

Comment: sure. post edited

Comment: Not sure if it's exactly what you're asking, but see https://stackoverflow.com/a/27210932/1361506

Comment: Yes thanks. Write this as answer

Comment: A `Writable` is a generic serializable object in MapReduce. Much like an `E` is a generic element in Java Collections.